# User + friend tagged photos

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get all then photos of the user + the selected friend using Facebook Graph API. Ive tired using `/me/?fields=id,name,tagged.with(friendID).fields(picture)` but it greyed out and did not return any results.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/